# Why do I get the following error when I try to use a struct template as agregation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, struct, linked-list

What I'm trying to do is simulate the ArrayList from java in c++  using linked List as a way of studying for my coming up exam.

This is What I written so far.

This is the header file...

```
#ifndef ArrayList_H
#define ArrayList_H
#include "ArrayListNode.h"
template<class T>
class ArrayList
{
private:
    ArrayListNode<T>* head;
    int length;

public:
    ~ArrayList();        //Destructor.
    ArrayList();         //Constructor.
    void add(T);        //Append an element at the last position.
    void display(); //Display all element in the list.
    void remove(int);   //Remove element at specify index
    void clear();       //Remove all the elements from the list.
    T get(int);         //Return the element at the specified position.
    bool isEmpty();     //Return true if this list contains no elements.
    int size();         //Return the length of the list.

};
#endif
```

Now This is the implementation file:

```
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    length = 0;
}

template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList()
{
    ArrayListNode<T>* traverse = head;
    ArrayListNode<T>* nextNode;

    while (traverse != nullptr)
    {
        nextNode = traverse->next;
        delete traverse;
        traverse = nextNode;
    }
}

template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::add(T item)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new ArrayListNode;
        head->item = item;
        head->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayListNode<T>* traverse = head;  
        ArrayListNode<T>* newNode = new ArrayListNode;
        newNode->item = item;
        newNode->next = nullptr;

        //Find the last node in the list
        while (traverse->next)
        {
            traverse = traverse->next;
        }
        traverse->next = newNode;
    }
}

template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::display()
{
    if (head == nullptr)
        return;
    else
    {
        ArrayListNode<T>* traverse = head;
        while (traverse->next)
        {
            cout<< traverse->item << endl;
            traverse = traverse->next;
        }
    }
}
template<class T>
void ArrayList<T> ::remove(int index)
{

}
template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::clear()
{

}
template<class T>
T ArrayList<T>::get(int index)
{

    return;
}

template<class T>
bool ArrayList<T>::isEmpty()
{

}
template<class T>
int ArrayList<T>::size()
{
    return length;
}
```

So far... I only created the constructor, destructor, display which display the items in the list.I also created the function  add which append an item
at the last position. The other methods are just empty. But I'm getting an error from the add function.

Here is the struct of the class...

```
template<class T>
struct ArrayListNode
{
    T item;                 //To hold any data.
    ArrayListNode<T>* next; //To point to the next node
};
```

Here is the main of the class...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include "ArrayList.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ArrayList<int> list;

    list.add(5);
    list.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile the program without the add function it compile correctly however, once I call the add function I get the following error.

```
c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\arraylist.cpp(31): error C2955: 'ArrayListNode': use of class template requires template argument list
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\arraylistnode.h(5): note: see declaration of 'ArrayListNode'
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\arraylist.cpp(28): note: while compiling class template member function 'void ArrayList<int>::add(T)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\main.cpp(9): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void ArrayList<int>::add(T)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\main.cpp(7): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'ArrayList<int>' being compiled
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\arraylist.cpp(31): error C2512: 'ArrayListNode': no appropriate default constructor available
1>c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\arraylist\arraylist.cpp(38): error C2512: 'ArrayListNode': no appropriate default constructor available
```

Comment: `head = new ArrayListNode` here's the template parameters missing. Also you should read about the rule of three.

Comment: @DanielJour Yeah I know about the rule of three.. You need copy constructor, destructor, and overload the assignment  operator  =

Comment: @DanielJour Hey, I don't need it, because I have a condition that says, if it is null  create new  node else append a new node

Comment: *"simulate the ArrayList from java in c++ using linked List"* - You want to study a Java collection class by writing some completely unrelated code in C++? Why?! If you want to study a Java collection class, then by all means use Java. Comparing Java collection classes to C++ container classes is an exercise in futility because typical C++ containers (the standard ones as well as your self-made one) own their contents while Java collections store pointers to contents whose ownerships may be shared.

Comment: @ChristianHackl To be honest I just want to practice using linked list... And my next exam is in linked list using c++, and since I already know java, I want to perform some operations  like add,clear,delete and some on. It just happens I like the name ArrayList and got some of the methods names from the ArrayList class.